# Contar letras/palabras en C++

Tags: c++

en el cole me piden un programa que cuente letras y palabras de un texto. Cual creen que es la mejor estructura de datos para hacerlo (teniendo en cuenta eficiencia) y quisiera que me expliquen por que y me orienten en como hacerlo. Gracias!
PD: No podemos hacerlo de la forma convencional, si o si debemos usar alguna estructura de datos que vimos, que son (lista, pila, cola, tabla de hash, metodos de ordenamiento y busqueda).

Answer (score 0):

Claro que si compañero!!,

Es asi como yo lo haria:

antes de todo, no olvides de escribir `#include <iostream>  using namespace std` al inicio de tu codigo

Primero creo la variable (que por ahora no contiene ningun valor)

```
  string texto= "";
```

Solicito el texto el cual va a ser contado

```
  cout << "Escribe tu texto: \n";
```

Almaceno el texto en la varaible anteriormente creada

```
getline(cin, texto);
```

Luego cuento las letras y las almaceno en una variable

```
int longitud = texto.length();
```

Luego, para contar las palabras, tendre que contar la cantidad de " " (espacios) que hay, y eso nos indicara las veces que las letras se separan (es decir por cada palabra)

Primero creo una variable que indicara la cantidad de palabras que se hallen

```
 int c = 1;
```

Luego llevo a cabo una condicion `for` que indicara la repeticion constante de una funcion hasta que una variable llegue a un valor indicado

esta va a contener un `if`, que va a sumarle 1 a la variable nativa del `for` (i), hasta que no hallan mas espacios en el texto

```
for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++) {
        if ((texto[i] == ' ' && texto[i + 1] != ' ')) {
            c = c + 1;
        }
    }
```

y luego imprimo el mensaje que le va a decir al emisor, la cantidad de caracteres/letras y palabras que contiene el texto que anteriormente ingresó

```
cout<<"La cantidad de palabras es: "<<c;
cout<<" y la cantidad de letras es: "<<longitud;
```

EL CODIGO COMPLETO SERIA ALGO COMO:

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;
int main()
{
string texto= "";

  cout << "Escribe tu texto:\n";
  getline(cin, texto);
  int longitud = texto.length();
  int c = 1;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++) {
        if ((texto[i] == ' ' && texto[i + 1] != ' ')) {
            c = c + 1;
        }
    }
    cout<<"La cantidad de palabras es: "<<c;
cout<<" y la cantidad de letras es: "<<longitud;
}
```